# turning characters array into integers

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, integer

So, I'm trying to check every character that is entered into the array, not just the first character, to determine if it's a letter or number. I used to ascii scale to determine this, which appears to work great, but it's only checking the first character. I also what to add 25 to what it entered if it is a valid input, but again, it's only adding 25 to the first number in the integer after I convert it. any ideas on how I can use a loop to do this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char CharNumInput[20]; // storage
    int Num = 0;
    
    cout << "Input Value -> "; // output
    cin >> CharNumInput; // input

    if (CharNumInput[0] >= 48 && CharNumInput[0] < 57) // **(TRUE)** checking to see if character is integer or letter by using ascii scale
    {
        cout << "Valid Input"; // ouput option 1
        Num = CharNumInput[0]; // converting character into integer
        Num -= 48; // setting correct integer from conversion
        Num = Num + 25; // compute
        cout << "Your Number plus 25 is " << Num << endl; // ouput
        cout << endl;
    }
    else // **(FALSE)**
        cout << "Invalid Input" << endl; // ouput option 2

    
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You tagged [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops), but you do not use any loop in the shown code.

Comment: i need a loop to check each character as needed. more than likely a while loop, i'm just unsure of how to set it up.

Comment: The answer to "any ideas on how I can fix this issue?" would be "use a loop". You seem to have another question, "how to use loops?". Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73993020/edit) your post to match the actual question.

Comment: Read about [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). Don't hardcode assumptions about character sets, and don't use magic numbers. And instead of `Num -= 48;` you can use `Num -= '0';`. Again, no hardcoded assumptions. (Both C and C++ require that the characters that represent digits are contiguous and increasing, so subtracting `'0'` from a digit will result in the value that the digit represents.

Comment: Don't use character arrays.  Arrays can underflow or overflow.  For example, what happens when I enter more than 20 characters to your prompt?  Use `std::string` and `std::getline`.  A lot safer.  The `std::string` manages memory for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be inside a for loop. Using `[0]` will just get the first index of the array and there is no code saying that the other indices should be checked, which will mean only the first character of your input is checked. The reason I used `strlen` in the loop is because getting `sizeof` won't take into consideration that most of the array is blank, and it will always return 20. If you don't need the array to be a fixed length, you can allocate it on the heap instead, which I will discuss later in my answer. Here's the code that fixes it.

 Note: I changed the decimal values of '9' and '0' to char literals to make the code more readable.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(CharNumInput); i++) {
        if (CharNumInput[i] >= '0' && CharNumInput[i] <= '9') // **(TRUE)** checking to see if character is integer or letter by using ascii scale
        {
            cout << "Valid Input"; // ouput option 1
            Num = CharNumInput[i]; // converting character into integer
            Num -= 48; // setting correct integer from conversion
            Num = Num + 25; // compute
            cout << "Your Number plus 25 is " << Num << endl; // ouput
            cout << endl;
        }
        else // **(FALSE)**
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl; // ouput option 2
        }
    }
```

To make the array on the heap:

```
    cout << "Input Value -> "; // Prompt user
    string tempStr; // Create a string to store the input
    char* CharNumInput; // Create a pointer to the start of our char array
    cin >> tempStr; // Save input to tempStr
    CharNumInput = new char[tempStr.length()]; // Create a char array with the length of the user input
    tempStr.copy(CharNumInput, tempStr.length()); // Save the user input in the char array

    for (int i = 0; i < tempStr.length(); i++) {
```

Keep in mind that this is absolutely pointless unless you cannot use a string and truly need a `char[]`. Note that the beginning of the for loop is slightly changed, as we can just use the length of the string to loop through the `char[]`.

Comment: Though a great point was made about not hardcoding character set assumptions. Look into other functions to check if a char is a digit. Also there is probably a way to check a string and avoid char arrays if there is no other reason to use one.

Comment: ````bool isNumber(string str)
{
    for (char c : str) {
        if (std::isdigit(c) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}```` Works great for checking if a string is an integer. Using ````stoi```` would let you get the integer it represents after checking it.

Comment: As you wanted to learn more about loops, I suggest looking into the c++ 11 ranged for loop, as it can be very useful.

Comment: Rather than using `48`, you should be using `'0'` regardless of whether OP is using it or not.  Not many people have the ASCII table memorized, especially in decimal.